# Create ListAdapter from a JSON

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, gson

I'm getting some problem in an Android APP: I want to read info from a Feed RSS and present them in some android view. 
I'm using the `android-async-http1.4.3.jar` libs to connect my APP to this site: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=10&q=http://f1grandprix.motorionline.com/feed/

With this connection I'm downloading the XML file and I'm transforming it into a JSON file with gson libs, but when i try the APP to my Android Phone I'm getting a Null Pointer Exception. The class to connect, to get the xml and to transform it into JSON code is the following:

```
    private void loadTitle() {
    String URL = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=10&q=http://f1grandprix.motorionline.com/feed/";

    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

    client.get(URL, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String text) {
            super.onSuccess(text);

            Gson decoder = new Gson();

            JsonResponse jr = decoder.fromJson(text, JsonResponse.class);

            Entry[] entries = jr.responseData.feed.entries;
            for (int i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
                Log.d("NET", "Il titolo della " + i + " entry è: " + entries[i].title);
            }


            final ListView lv_title = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_title);
            //ListAdapter la_title = new TitleAdapter(MainActivity.this, entries);
            //Log.d("LIST_ADAPTER", "Caricato correttamente il list adaptor: "+ la_title);
            //lv_title.setAdapter(la_title);
            lv_title.setAdapter(new TitleAdapter(MainActivity.this, entries));
            pleaseWait.hide();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable arg0, String arg1) {
            super.onFailure(arg0, arg1);
            Log.d("FAIL", "Failure");
            pleaseWait.hide();
        }
    });
}
```

The TitleAdapter.java is the following:

```
public class TitleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Entry> {

public TitleAdapter(Context context, Entry[] title) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_item, R.id.lv_title, title);
}
```

}

And finally I'm getting this error:

```
02-23 12:46:05.525: E/AndroidRuntime(4577): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-23 12:46:05.525: E/AndroidRuntime(4577): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-23 12:46:05.525: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:355)
02-23 12:46:05.525: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
02-23 12:46:05.525: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1495)
02-23 12:46:05.525: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1216)
02-23 12:46:05.525: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1127)
02-23 12:46:05.525: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8335)
02-23 12:46:05.525: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:566)
02-23 12:46:05.525: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:381)
02-23 12:46:05.525: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8335)
02-23 12:46:05.525: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
02-23 12:46:05.525: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
02-23 12:46:05.525: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8335)
02-23 12:46:05.525: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:531)
02-23 12:46:05.525: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
02-23 12:46:05.525: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8335)
02-23 12:46:05.525: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
02-23 12:46:05.525: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
02-23 12:46:05.525: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8335)
02-23 12:46:05.525: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:843)
02-23 12:46:05.525: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1892)
02-23 12:46:05.525: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-23 12:46:05.525: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-23 12:46:05.525: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
02-23 12:46:05.525: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-23 12:46:05.525: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-23 12:46:05.525: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
02-23 12:46:05.525: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
02-23 12:46:05.525: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can someone help me to fix this problem?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone help me to fix this problem?

In the `entries` array that you pass to your custom `ArrayAdapter`(for which you still call the `super.getView()` method(or you didn't overriden it), right?) it appears that you have `null` values. This is a problem if you use the default implementation of `ArrayAdapter`'s `getView()` method, as `ArrayAdapter` will call in that method, by default, the `toString()` method on its  type object(`Entry` object in your case) to obtain a `String` to show in the row.

So make sure the array that you pass to your implementation of the `ArrayAdapter` **doesn't** contain null values.

Comment: Thank you! It was a nice suggest!